# Mapping query on 2 different DB schemas

Tags: mysql, sql, database, migration, schema

What I have here is an old DB schema, which we optimize to a new one.

More than 250 tables where translation into 70 tables.

We have moved all data from the old schema to the new one.

The issue is that we rely on the sql.log to parse live incoming queries which are built for the old schema because we have not yet moved the new schema to live.

Is there a tool, or a strategy to follow that would help us parse these queries, compare the altered table and columns so it can be run based on the new schema?

With other words, is there a way to translate a query or map it to affect the new schema, by using the names and columns of the old schema's tables?

Thanks a lot, hope I was clear enough